# How do I exclude specific source branches from CI triggers for an Azure Repos Git project?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm hoping to somehow replicate the functionality of [PR triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#pr-triggers) which, according to the docs, are currently only supported for GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud repos. I'd like my CI pipelines to not trigger if the change is incoming from certain branches.

I've mostly tried to solve this problem with GitVersion, which is the part of my pipeline that makes it problematic to trigger builds when I'm merging back from a `release` build or `master` back onto `develop`. So far I've had no luck, so now I'm hoping I've overlooked a feature of Azure Pipelines which will help.

My current pipeline trigger:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
  paths:
    exclude:
      - ReadMe.md
      - development-pipeline.yml
      - release-pipeline.yml
      - GitVersion.yml
```

I'd like a pull request which originated in a `release` branch (can be identified with the regex pattern `[Rr]eleases?[\/-]`) or `master` to not trigger my pipeline. In reality, any change to the `develop` branch triggers the build.

Comment: Why not exclude the branches in the `branches` section?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk the `branches` section determines which branches to scan for changes. You can also use wildcards in both cases. So you could combine `include` and `exclude` to do something like `include: feature/*` and `exclude feature/UNSTABLE/*`. But that means both are related to the target branch rather than the source branch, so it's unfortunately not usable for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the develop branch not to trigger ci build, then you can check "Enable continuous integration" option in the Continuous integration of builds Triggers and set exclude develop branch in the branch filters.

If you want some source branches to trigger the CI build of the develop branch, some can't. I am afraid that this feature you want is not achievable. Once your deveop branch
Enable continuous integration, then the deveop branch will trigger the build pipeline once it changes.

If you want to merge the commits on the release or master branch into the develop branch, and create pr does not trigger the CI build, you could enable the build policy in the Build validation in the branch policy.In this way, only after PR is completed will CI build be triggered.But pr build is unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, but unfortunately that won't work for us. We need to be sure that all code on the development branch has been reviewed so we have the Minimum Reviewers policy set on the branch. So merging from release or master to develop has to happen by pull request too.